# Php put this in global var

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I have loop and inside generate some values , i need insert this values in global var , but the format show no right because give me errors

```
global ${$search}[$exp_t];
```

I need use this yes or yes and insert in global var , because it´s necesary for works my function but i don´t know if i writte bad because give me error or if howewer it´s necessary writte in different way to this

I try other ways for works but no get good results , in the loop generatre strings with values and for example the values has this format : $search[name] , $search[phone] , etc , and i need show inside bucle the same as global $search[name] , global $search[phone], etc , etc

Thank´s the best regards

More Code

```
function showcode()
{
foreach($exp_tabla as $exp_t)
{
//global ${$exp_t}; 
///$val=${$search}[$exp_t];
///global $$search[$exp_t];
$GLOBALS['search'][$exp_t];
}
}


echo $search[alias];
```

More or less the function mus works in this way

Comment: `$GLOBALS['search'][$exp_t]`

Comment: I try that inside function but when i put function and try do this echo $search[phone]; no show nothing , regards

Comment: More code to show what you need to do.

Comment: I put more code for understand the idea , thank´s for your help

Comment: Where is `$exp_tabla` defined? Why do you want to work with global rather than pass the data in to function by reference for modification or set the value in the global namespace based upon the return (i.e. `$search = showcode();` or similar)? That is a much better design.

Comment: `echo $search[alias];` Do you have the `alias` constant defined? Or did you mean `echo $search['alias'];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reserved word `global` is for accessing a global variable from a function scope.

To define a new variable in a global scope use:

`$GLOBALS[$search][$exp_t]`

If `$search` contains `foo`, you'll have the variable `$foo` defined in a global scope.

Example:

```
function set_foo() {
    $search = 'foo';
    $GLOBALS[$search] = 'bar';
}

set_foo();
var_dump($foo);
```

...will output `string(3) "bar"`

If you want to define a variable named `search` in a global scope, just use `$GLOBALS['search'] = 'bar';`.

`$GLOBALS[$search] = 'bar';` will define a variable named according to what the variable `$search` contains.

Also if you use `$foo[test]` you have to define a constant `test` first. Constants should be named in uppercase, so:

```
define('TEST', 'foo');
$GLOBALS[TEST] = 'bar';
```

...that will create a variable `$foo` with the content "bar" in a global scope.

Also enable **error_reporting** (`E_ALL`) and **display_errors** in your PHP configuration. If you would have it enabled, you know that your code was a nonsense. That's the first thing you should do on your development machine.

And also read at least basics of PHP programming, because according to the code you have presented here, you have no clue, what you're doing :)